# How to remove all-N sequence entries from fasta file(s)

Tags: python, perl, awk

I would like to remove entries of a fasta file where all nucleotides are N, but not entries which contain ACGT and N nucleotides.

from an example of input file content:

```
#>seq_1
TGCTAGCTAGCTGATCGTGTCGATCG
CACCACANNNNNCACGTGTCG
#>seq2
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNN
#>seq3
catgcatcgacgatgctgacgatc
#>seq4
cacacaccNNNNttgtgca
#...
```

Hoping the output file content to be:

```
#>seq_1
TGCTAGCTAGCTGATCGTGTCGATCG
CACCACANNNNNCACGTGTCG
#>seq3
catgcatcgacgatgctgacgatc
#>seq4
cacacaccNNNNttgtgca
#...
```

Any suggestions in doing this with awk, perl, python, other?
Thank you!
FDS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With python, using the BioPython module:

```
import Bio

INPUT  = "bio_input.fas"
OUTPUT = "bio_output.fas"

def main():
    records = Bio.SeqIO.parse(INPUT, 'fasta')
    filtered = (rec for rec in records if any(ch != 'N' for ch in rec.seq))
    Bio.SeqIO.write(filtered, OUTPUT, 'fasta')

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

however note that the FastA spec says sequence ids are supposed to start with `>`, not `#>`!

Run against

```
>seq_1
TGCTAGCTAGCTGATCGTGTCGATCG
CACCACANNNNNCACGTGTCG
>seq2
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>seq3
catgcatcgacgatgctgacgatc
>seq4
cacacaccNNNNttgtgca
```

this produces

```
>seq_1
TGCTAGCTAGCTGATCGTGTCGATCGCACCACANNNNNCACGTGTCG
>seq3
catgcatcgacgatgctgacgatc
>seq4
cacacaccNNNNttgtgca
```

(Note, the default linewrap length is 60 chars).

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk

```
awk -v RS='#>seq[[:digit:]]+' '!/^[N\n]+$/{printf "%s",term""$0}; {term=RT}' file
#>seq_1
TGCTAGCTAGCTGATCGTGTCGATCG
CACCACANNNNNCACGTGTCG
#>seq3
catgcatcgacgatgctgacgatc
#>seq4
cacacaccNNNNttgtgca
```

Answer (score 0):

So essentially blocks start with a #> marker, and you wish to remove blocks where no line contains anything other than N. One way in Python:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import fileinput, sys, re

block=[]
nonN=re.compile('[^N\n]')
for line in fileinput.input():
    if line.startswith('#>'):
        if len(block)==1 or any(map(nonN.search, block[1:])):
            sys.stdout.writelines(block)
        block=[line]
    else:
        block.append(line)
if len(block)==1 or any(map(nonN.search, block[1:])):
    sys.stdout.writelines(block)
```

Answer (score 0):

in python using regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
ff = open('test', 'r')
data = ff.read()
ff.close()

m = re.compile(r'(#>seq\d+[N\n]+)$', re.M)
f = re.sub(m, '', data)

fo = open('out', 'w')
fo.write(f)
fo.close()
```

and you will get in your out file:

```
#>seq_1
TGCTAGCTAGCTGATCGTGTCGATCG
CACCACANNNNNCACGTGTCG

#>seq3
catgcatcgacgatgctgacgatc
#>seq4
cacacaccNNNNttgtgca
#...
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

With shell command egrep (grep + regrex)

```
egrep -B 1 "^[^NNNN && ^#seq]" your.fa >conert.fa
# -B 1 means print match row and the previous row
# ^[^NNNN && ^#seq] is regrex pattern means not match with (begin with NNNN and 
# #seq)
```

so only match with begin with common A/T/G/C sequence row and its previous row which is fasta header

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what the code does and how it helps.