# Trim fasta files using BioPython

Tags: python-3.x, trim, biopython, fasta

I have a fasta file with multiple sequences in it. Some of the sequences are trailed with '-' and I'd like to trim them from the final sequences. Is there a clean way to trim them and write a new fasta file without the dashes using Biopython?

I saw this post [How to remove all-N sequence entries from fasta file(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886699/how-to-remove-all-n-sequence-entries-from-fasta-files) and tried to adapt some of the code but it didn't work...

file containing a sequence like this:

> sequence_of_interest
>   CAGGCCATTTCACCTAGAACTTTAAATGCATGGGTAAAAGTAGTAGAAGAGAAGGCTTTTAGCCCAGAAGTAATACCCATGTTTTCAGCATTATCAGAAGGAGCCACCCCACAAGATTTAAACACCATGCTAAACACAGTGGGGGGACATCAAGCAGCAATGCAAATGTTAAAAGAGACCATCAATGAGGAAGCTGCAGAATGGGATAGATTGCATCCAGTGCACGCAGGGCCTATTGCACCAGGCCAGATGAGAGAA---------------------------------------------------------------

```
def dash_removal(file_in, file_out):
    records = SeqIO.parse(file_in, 'fasta')
    filtered = (rec for rec in records if any(ch != '-' for ch in rec.seq))
    SeqIO.write(filtered, file_out, 'fasta')
    dash_removal("dash_removal_test.fasta", "dashes_gone?.fasta")
```

all of the sequences should ultimately be trimmed to look like this:

> sequence_of_interest
>   CAGGCCATTTCACCTAGAACTTTAAATGCATGGGTAAAAGTAGTAGAAGAGAAGGCTTTTAGCCCAGAAGTAATACCCATGTTTTCAGCATTATCAGAAGGAGCCACCCCACAAGATTTAAACACCATGCTAAACACAGTGGGGGGACATCAAGCAGCAATGCAAATGTTAAAAGAGACCATCAATGAGGAAGCTGCAGAATGGGATAGATTGCATCCAGTGCACGCAGGGCCTATTGCACCAGGCCAGATGAGAGAA

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `sed -i~ 's/-*$//' *.fasta` will simply remove all trailing dashes from all lines, is that sufficient?

Comment: Heh. I read the title and thought it was slang for "trim files faster"

Comment: Seems to have worked! Thanks!

Comment: If I wanted to run this from within python, how would I modify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the options using `sed` are great because they are faster but here is a way to do it in `BioPython`.

The idea is to use `rstrip` on the `seq` attribute of each record. `rstrip` can be used on the sequence just like on any other string in Python.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import io

seq = """>sequence_of_interest
CAGGCCATTTCACCTAGAACTTTAAATGCATGGGTAAAAGTAGTAGAAGAGAAGGCTTTTAGCCCAGAAGTAATACCCAT
GTTTTCAGCATTATCAGAAGGAGCCACCCCACAAGATTTAAACACCATGCTAAACACAGTGGGGGGACATCAAGCAGCAA
TGCAAATGTTAAAAGAGACCATCAATGAGGAAGCTGCAGAATGGGATAGATTGCATCCAGTGCACGCAGGGCCTATTGCA
CCAGGCCAGATGAGAGAA--------------------------------------------------------------"""

f = io.StringIO(seq) # replace it with f = open('my_fasta.fa', 'r')
clean_records = []
for record in SeqIO.parse(f, "fasta"):
    record.seq = record.seq.rstrip('-')
    clean_records.append(record)

with open('clean_fasta.fa', 'w') as f:
    SeqIO.write(clean_records, f, 'fasta')
```